# In htaccess if the like have as symbol '-' and same time the parameter also having '-' that time url is not working how to solve this?

Tags: .htaccess

### Example

*www.domainname.com/page-param1-param2.html*

...it will work fine but

*www.domainname.com/page-param-1-param2.html*

... here param one have the data like *param-1* this time url is not working.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you should use a different syntax, perhaps - there's no way to tell whether it should interpret the "1" as part of the first parameter or not. Alternatively, you could escape the - in "param-1" by encoding the - as "%2D" (no quotes).

So for example, your link would be: http://www.domainname.com/page-param%2D1-param2.html

Comment: http://www.domainname.com/page-param%2D1-param2.html . if use like this the url link in the address field is showing in place of '-' as '%2D' . but for you it showing correcly like '-' you said encode the taht means string replacement ?

Comment: No, it's intended to show %2D in the address bar. You'll have to choose a parameter separator other than '-' if you want to have dashes in your parameter values AND don't want to show %2D in the address bar.